# What can we conclude if this set is empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be functions that result in $0$ or $1$.
Let $S$ be a set. Let $X = \{i \in S: f_1(i) = f_2(i) = 1\}$.

If $X=\varnothing$, we can conclude that

1. $f_1 (i) = f_2 (i) = 0$ for every $i \in S$;
2. $f_1 (i) = 0$ or $f_2(i) = 0$ for every $i \in S$.

What is correct? I think that $2$ is correct (because will be the negation of set). I am correct?

Comment: Negation of set?

Comment: Neither $1$ nor $2$ are correct. The $f_i$ could be the constant functions to $3$, say

Comment: Negation of the expression: $r_1(i) = 1$ and $r_2(i) = 1$ for every $i \in S$ corresponds $r_1(i) = 0$ or $r_2(i) = 0$ for every $i \in S$

Comment: No it doesn't, even if the $f_i$'s (not "$r_i$"'s) were from $S$ to $\{0,1\}$ instead of your "integer non-negatives" (see FShrike's comment). Edit: you just corrected your typos but the negation of $\forall x\;P(x)$ is $\exists x\;\neg P(x)$.

Comment: I'm sorry $f_1(i) \in \{0,1\}$ and $f_2(i) \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Are the respective domains of the $f_i$'s supposed to contain $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2. conclusion is correct.
Because as @Thesco already commented: $f_1(i),f_2(i) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $i \in S$.

If the set $X$ contains no elements, then the condition to be an element of the set is not met. That means there is no $i \in S$ to satisfy the condition. The condition is false or in other words the negation of the condition is true.

Now whats the negation of the expression $f_1(i)=f_2(i)=0$? Lets have a look. First we can rewrite the expression.
$$
f_1(i)=f_2(i)=0 \Longleftrightarrow f_1(i)=0 \land f_2(i)=0
$$
Now we can form the negation
$$
\lnot (f_1(i)=0 \land f_2(i)=0) \Longleftrightarrow f_1(i) \neq 0 \lor f_2(i) \neq 0
$$
What does that mean? It means that $f_1(i)=0$ or $f_2(i)=0$ for every $i \in S$. So yes, you are indeed correct! Think about why the 1. conclusion must be incorrect.

Hope that helps.